# Runtime error 1004 for code that worked fine

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code in a spreadsheet that's been used for months in the office:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    With Sheets("Summary").Range("B2:H83")
        .ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="F:\Export.pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
    End With

End Sub
```

Today, when I try to execute I get a Runtime error 1004.

We did a recent Office 365 update, could that be the culprit?

Comment: Your code should work just fine, my guess is that `"F:\Export.pdf"` is your culprit. Do you have access to this location?

Comment: Actually the culprit seems to be that when I plug my laptop into my dock the runtime error occurs, when I run the code without the dock, it works fine